# How to create an ember model from json file

Tags: json, ember.js, autocomplete, models

I am new to ember and I have a question about the models.

I got a "key":["value1, "value2] list in a json-file. The keys and the values are arbitrary and I want to hold that list in the (DS.)store. To use it for an autocomplete and some other stuff.

Is there a  sophisticated way to create a model from a json file, including the keys? All the examples I have found until now it was always a predefined key and a arbitrary value. 
Of course I can iterate over the keys first but is there a nicer way?

The purpose is to create an auto-complete application which suggests the user first the keys and when a key is selected the possible values. But when the user starts searching he will get a new keyword file and the auto-complete function shall be updated with that new data.

My auto-complete is based on this tutorial http://www.embercasts.com/episodes/building-an-autocomplete-widget-part-1

Thanks for your help, I hope it's not the dumbest question ever^^ If you know nice tutorials or stuff I would appreciate links too:)

Comment: You won't want to use Ember Data if you are creating dynamic objects that don't have consistent properties.  In fact how do you plan on using the objects without knowing the keys before hand?  In the scenario where you have a set of key:[values...] and your autocomplete shows the key as the visible item.  I'm gonna need more  info, but we can find a good solution for you.

Comment: I updated my question, do you think it might be better to extract the key-value list by just using plain java-script and just passing an array of values to my autocomplete? Do you know any good links to get an better overview about ember and it's possibilities and restrictions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I completely understand the question, but you can load arbitrary payloads into the the data store by calling [pushPayload](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_pushPayload)

```
var pushData = {
  autocompleteObjects: [
    {id: 1, value1: "foo", value2: "bar"}
  ]
}    
store.pushPayload('autocompleteObject', pushData)
```

Maybe in your app you could get for the JSON file and push the payload?